# How to assign primitive type value to a method args using Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I'm new to java reflection concept. I need to access one method from a particular class using Java reflection. That method has three different types of argument like this,

```
public void print(int start, String middle, int end) {
   System.out.println(start);
   System.out.println(middle);
   System.out.println(end);
}
```

I tried to call that method like this,

```
...
method.invoke(null, "middle", null);
...
```

I got **IllegalArgumentException**. I know null is acceptable for wrapper type args, but I just tried this method for knowing how it is working.

So, my main question is, how to pass primitive type value to that method argument via reflection?
also, how to pass default value for primitive type arg via reflection? (for eg: let's assume, I don't need end arg value during runtime, then how to pass 0 for end arg)

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please share the complete stracktrace?

Comment: A primitive type cannot be `null`. If you want to use `null` as a parameter, you would have to change the `int` to `Integer`.

Comment: Pass an `Integer`; you can probably also just pass an `int` value and let autoboxing automatically turn it into an `Integer`.  So if you would have called `print(0,"xxx",1)`, just use `printMethod.invoke(0,"xxx",1)` or `printMethod.invoke(Integer.valueOf(0), "xxx", Integer.valueOf(1))`

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with primitive types. Since this method is not `static`, you must provide an object, to invoke the method on, just as simple as `method.invoke(object, 100, "middle", 42)`. Even for `static` methods, the first argument is needed, as the method signature is [`invoke​(Object obj,
Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object...%29), so you would have to insert a `null` at the beginning for `static` methods, followed by the method arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have this class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public void print(int start, String middle, int end) {
        System.out.println(start);
        System.out.println(middle);
        System.out.println(end);
    }

}
```

You can use the following code to:

1. Instantiate the class using reflection
2. Fetch the desired method
3. Call the desired method using reflection

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        var instance = Class
        .forName(SomeClass.class.getName())
        .getConstructor()
        .newInstance();
        var printMethod = SomeClass.class.getMethod("print", int.class, String.class, int.class);
        printMethod.invoke(instance, 0, "it's me", 0);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.err.println("An error has occurred while accessing method");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Note that for primitive values there is no need to pass is `null`. For those cases, you need to supply a value, which in turn means calling the method reflectively like so:

`printMethod.invoke(instance, 0, "it's me", 0);`

Note that this would be the same as calling the method directly, as in this case as well attempting to pass in `null` as method argument for integers would result in a compilation error.

Comment: Hi, @akortex91 . Thanks for the response. In this example, you get and call the method directly by using the method name. But, in my use case, the class has a list of methods, I get that particular method using the method name. Let's assume that a particular method has 3 args but I have only 2 values. I tried this code
`Object[] input = new Object[method.getParameterCount()];
method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), input);`
In this case, let's assume that the input array looks like this after inserting the 2 values
`[1, "hi"];`
then which type of value I need to pass for the 3rd argument?